# PHP registration form problems, database not receiving data

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a login system that use to work perfectly, I was editing in and my pc lost power, there is a mistake somewhere and i can not see if for looking.

Can anyone spot it?

```
    <?php
if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
header("location: home.php");
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Network TV Registration</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body style="background-image: url(http://axeetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/downtown_nightime_wallpaper_4k.jpeg); background-size: 100%">
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="row">
 <div class=".col-md-4">
    <div id="login-overlay" class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-body">
                  <div class="row">
                  <h3><center><u>Network TV Registration</u></center></h3>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class=".col-md-4">
    <div id="login-overlay" class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-6">
                      <div class="">
                          <form id="register-form" action="" method="post" role="form">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label for="username" class="control-label">Username </label>
                                  <span class="form-control-feedback input-validator-feedback" data-fieldname="username"></span>
                                  <input type="text" name="newusername" id="newusername" tabindex="1" class="form-control validate-input" placeholder="Username" value="" autocomplete="off">
                                  <span class="help-block"></span>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label for="password" class="control-label">Password</label>
                                  <input type="password" name="newpassword1" id="password" tabindex="10" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off">
                                  <span class="help-block"></span>
                              </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                  <label for="email" class="control-label">Email Address</label>
                                  <span class="form-control-feedback input-validator-feedback" data-fieldname="email"></span>
                                  <input type="email" name="newemail" id="newemail" tabindex="2" class="form-control validate-input" placeholder="Email Address" value="" autocomplete="off">
                                  <span class="help-block"></span>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label for="name" class="control-label">Name</label>
                                  <span class="form-control-feedback input-validator-feedback" data-fieldname="name"></span>
                                  <input type="text" name="newname" id="newname" tabindex="3" class="form-control validate-input" placeholder="First name" value="" autocomplete="off">
                                  <span class="help-block"></span>
                              </div>
                              <input type="submit" name="register-submit" id="register-submit" tabindex="12" class="form-control btn btn-success" value="Register">
                          </form>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-6">
                      <p class="lead">Register now for <span class="text-success">FREE</span></p>
                      <ul class="list-unstyled" style="line-height: 2">
                      <br>
                          <li><span class="fa fa-check text-success"></span>100% totally free!</li>
                          <p>
                          <li><span class="fa fa-check text-success"></span>Over 500 Movies!</li>
                          <p>
                          <li><span class="fa fa-check text-success"></span>Quick and easy search!</li>
                          <p>
                          <li><span class="fa fa-check text-success"></span>Fast and free 24/7 streaming!</li>
                          <p>
                          <li><span class="fa fa-check text-success"></span>Account customisation!</li>
                          <p>
                          <li><span class="fa fa-check text-success"></span>100% Free Movie Download!</li>
                          <p>
                          <li><span class="fa fa-check text-success"></span>Free messaging system!</li>
                      </ul>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  </div>
 <div class=".col-md-4">
    <div id="login-overlay" class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-body">
                  <div class="row">
                      <ul class="list-unstyled" style="line-height: 2; text-align: center">
                      <li><span class="text-success"></span><u><h3>Site Information</h3></u></li>
                          <li></span> Number of videos:</li>
                          <li></span> Number of users registerd:</li>
                          <li></span> Number of admins:</li>
                          <li></span> Fast checkout:</li>
                      </ul>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>

</div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>







<?php
If($_POST){
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","password_here");
    mysql_select_db("users");
    if(isset($_POST['register-submit'])){
    $user_name = $_POST['newusername'];
    $password = $_POST['newpassword1'];
    $email = $_POST['newemail'];
    $name = $_POST['newname'];
    }
    $passwordmd5 = md5($password);
    $query = "insert into username (username,password,email,name) values ('$user_name','$passwordmd5','$email','$name')";
    $query = "DELETE FROM username WHERE username = ''";

    mysql_connect("localhost","root","Oliver");
    mysql_select_db("videos");
    $query = "DELETE FROM videos WHERE name = ''";

    if (mysql_query($query)){
        echo 'registration successful';
        exit;
    }

}
?>
```

I'm sure its something to do with the `$query` but can't see the mistake.
However if I copy the query and substitute data like so `insert into username (username,password,email,name) values ('Usernamehere','Passwordhere','Emailhere','Namehere')` it workes fine, so maybe its something to do with the form, not sure.

**Thanks in advance**

**New code**

```
<?php
If($_POST){
mysql_connect("localhost","root","Oliver");
mysql_select_db("users");

$query = "insert into username (username,password,email,name) values ('$user_name','$passwordmd5','$email','$name')";
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_query($query)){
echo '<center><h1 style="color: green">!Registation Suncessfull!</h1></center>';
}

?>
```

Gets me error code
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in register.php on line 134

Comment: If there was a list of bad mysql practices, you followed them all. Also, you never execute your insert query.

Comment: maybe I followed that list, sorry, i'm new, wanna help me? :D

Comment: Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

Comment: Thanks Ill take a look now. Im sure its a super simple fix, this code use to work before

Comment: When you write a question about an error, always __always__ include details of the error. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); `then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: You're welcome, but I seriously doubt that your code as you posted, "used" to work. Not what you posted anyway.

Comment: I'd suggest you completely refactor that code following better practices, like changing `mysql_` to newer conn apis such as suggested in the comments and @rray answer, paremeterize your query to avoid SQL injections and read some examples of efficient and simples MySQL+PHP CRUD routines. Then you test it again and see if you get the same errors. Otherwise, there is just too many wrong things to consider.

Comment: Honestly I have another local domain running this code and it works fine, ill do the <?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); as you suggested.

Comment: is missing `}` for `if($_POST){` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don´t know if that code works, but if it does, the only query that gets executed is the last, just before

```
if (mysql_query($query))
```

that query is:

```
$query = "DELETE FROM videos WHERE name = ''";
```

so, the only thing your code does is deleting all the rows in the table 'videos' where the name is empty, and then it says "registration successful". Doesn't make sense.

If you want that each $query gets executed you should call mysql_query($query) after every $query = "" declaration, otherwise you are just changing the value of the variable without doing nothing with the new values.

Try this:

```
if($_POST){


    if(isset($_POST['register-submit'])){
    $user_name = $_POST['newusername'];
    $password = $_POST['newpassword1'];
    $email = $_POST['newemail'];
    $name = $_POST['newname'];
    $passwordmd5 = md5($password);
    $query = "insert into username (username,password,email,name) values ('$user_name','$passwordmd5','$email','$name')";   
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","Oliver");
    mysql_select_db("users");
        if (mysql_query($query)){
            echo 'registration successful';               
        } else {
            echo "registration error";
        }
    } else {
        echo "no register-submit";
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay I have deleted that, lets forget about the second query, I just need the first query to work, 'insert into username' that one

Comment: ok I just added an update with some code

Comment: Thanks man, works perfectly, you made a small syntax error on line 130, you put : instead of ;, but I fixed it, would you care to explain why my code would not run so i actually understand?

Comment: I'm glad it helped! Still you need to improve security problems in that code. Go on. PS: syntax error fixed

Comment: the problem was what I put at the first part of the answer, you where just assigning string values to $query variable but you only executed the last one, the delete videos query.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your rewriting `$query` with delete statement insted of insert.

Do not use mysql_* old function change the API for MYSQLi or PDO and use prepared statements.

```
$query = "insert into username (username,password,email,name) values ('$user_name','$passwordmd5','$email','$name')";
//reassign
$query = "DELETE FROM username WHERE username = ''";

mysql_connect("localhost","root","Oliver");
mysql_select_db("videos");
//reassign again!
$query = "DELETE FROM videos WHERE name = ''";

if (mysql_query($query)){
```

Fix this:

```
<?php
    if($_POST){
        mysql_connect("localhost","root","Oliver");
        mysql_select_db("users");
        $query = "insert into username (username,password,email,name) values ('$user_name','$passwordmd5','$email','$name')";
        if (mysql_query($query)){
            echo '<center><h1 style="color: green">!Registation Suncessfull!</h1></center>'; 
        }else{
            echo 'Erro: '. mysql_error();
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Currently trying to implement this code, give me a few minutes, thanks for the help.

Comment: Im having absolutely no success whatsoever

Comment: @OliverKetley no error messages?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\1\xx\register.php on line 134

Comment: <?php
If($_POST){
mysql_connect("localhost","root","Oliver");
mysql_select_db("users");

$query = "insert into username (username,password,email,name) values ('$user_name','$passwordmd5','$email','$name')";
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_query($query)){
echo '<center><h1 style="color: green">!Registation Suncessfull!</h1></center>';
}

?>

Comment: thats my code, ill update the post so its easier to read sorry

Answer (score 0):

Your Updated question as you posted with the:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in register.php on
>   line 134

has a missing `}` in the end. i.e `if($_POST){` Where is the ending `}` for it?

Furthermore, Instead of running the query twice like this:

```
$query = "insert into username (username,password,email,name) 
values ('$user_name','$passwordmd5','$email','$name')";
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_query($query)){
            echo 'registration successful';}
```

Make the changes as:

```
$res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
if ($res){
echo '<center><h1 style="color: green">!Registation Suncessfull!</h1></center>';
}
```

Fixed:

```
<?php
if($_POST){
mysql_connect("localhost","root","Oliver");
mysql_select_db("users");

$query = "insert into username (username,password,email,name) 
VALUES ('$user_name','$passwordmd5','$email','$name')";
$res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

if ($res){
echo '<center><h1 style="color: green">!Registation Suncessfull!</h1></center>';
}
}
?>
```

> Note: This is still *very* bad practice and I urge you to stop using
>   the *deprecated* mysql functions and move to either `mysqli` or `PDO`
>   with prepared statements to know why/how it helps.

[MySQL Improved Extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

[PHP Data Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: your edited the answer, it's ok now  ;)

Comment: @rray Ahh, Great minds think a like `;-)`

Comment: Okay Ill look it up, thanks for the heads up mate.

Comment: @OliverKetley You're welcome `:-)`